# How to speed up CSV import with searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import, sidekiq, searchkick

There’s a CSV file with 2mil records.

I iterate line by line and schedule a sidekick worker for each CSV row.
The worker finds the corresponding record in the db with searchkick and creates a new record based on the search result.

Is there any way to bulk update created records with the info from the search in one go or any other approach to speed up the process?

I have tried creating new records one by one using the search results info. Having 2 mil records will take almost 24 hours if not longer for background jobs to finish.

Comment: The overhead you are incurring to schedule a worker per row for 2mil rows is likely adding a lot of overhead, queuing, scheduling. If you don't have 2mil workers, and your DB can't handle 2mil connections, a lot of time will be spent setting up, waiting, & tearing down. Try batching jobs of 1,000-10,000 rows at a time. I'm not familiar with searchkick, but it sounds slow too. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Show how you've concluded that the creation of these new records is your bottleneck. Side note: without any data, the prime suspect for performance issues IMHO would be searchkick (or more accurately, the elasticsearch/opensearch backend behind searchkick), to that end have you implemented [the various performance steps suggested](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#performance) in the searchkick readme?